# Mapbox only visualize clusters in sight

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have this mapbox question which i haven't been able to solve.
I'm currently working on a little project where im using mapbox with clusters the code i have is from here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/ it works fine but I thought is there a way to only load/visualize the clusters that are in my "view" ?

Example. I'm zoomed in on San francisco so it should only load/show clusters & points from there and not load them in New York too in order to make map faster.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token-goes-here';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
center: [-103.5917, 40.6699],
zoom: 3
});
 
map.on('load', () => {
// Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and
// set the 'cluster' option to true. GL-JS will
// add the point_count property to your source data.
map.addSource('earthquakes', {
type: 'geojson',
// Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ earthquakes
// from 12/22/15 to 1/21/16 as logged by USGS' Earthquake hazards program.
data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson',
cluster: true,
clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
});
 
map.addLayer({
id: 'clusters',
type: 'circle',
source: 'earthquakes',
filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
paint: {
// Use step expressions (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-step)
// with three steps to implement three types of circles:
//   * Blue, 20px circles when point count is less than 100
//   * Yellow, 30px circles when point count is between 100 and 750
//   * Pink, 40px circles when point count is greater than or equal to 750
'circle-color': [
'step',
['get', 'point_count'],
'#51bbd6',
100,
'#f1f075',
750,
'#f28cb1'
],
'circle-radius': [
'step',
['get', 'point_count'],
20,
100,
30,
750,
40
]
}
});
 
map.addLayer({
id: 'cluster-count',
type: 'symbol',
source: 'earthquakes',
filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
layout: {
'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
'text-size': 12
}
});
 
map.addLayer({
id: 'unclustered-point',
type: 'circle',
source: 'earthquakes',
filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
paint: {
'circle-color': '#11b4da',
'circle-radius': 4,
'circle-stroke-width': 1,
'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
}
});
 
// inspect a cluster on click
map.on('click', 'clusters', (e) => {
const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
layers: ['clusters']
});
const clusterId = features[0].properties.cluster_id;
map.getSource('earthquakes').getClusterExpansionZoom(
clusterId,
(err, zoom) => {
if (err) return;
 
map.easeTo({
center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
zoom: zoom
});
}
);
});
 
// When a click event occurs on a feature in
// the unclustered-point layer, open a popup at
// the location of the feature, with
// description HTML from its properties.
map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', (e) => {
const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
const mag = e.features[0].properties.mag;
const tsunami =
e.features[0].properties.tsunami === 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';
 
// Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that
// multiple copies of the feature are visible, the
// popup appears over the copy being pointed to.
while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
}
 
new mapboxgl.Popup()
.setLngLat(coordinates)
.setHTML(
`magnitude: ${mag}<br>Was there a tsunami?: ${tsunami}`
)
.addTo(map);
});
 
map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', () => {
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', () => {
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> `data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson',`

So you're loading the whole GeoJSON at once. If you wanted to only load data for the current area you'd have to use vector tiles.

> I'm zoomed in on San francisco so it should only load/show clusters & points from there and not load them in New York too in order to make map faster.

Mapbox GL JS won't waste effort trying to show things that are outside the current viewport. You don't need to worry about that.